# Can't refactor files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, hgeclipse

I'm working on an Android project in eclipse, and whenever I try to move or rename a source file, eclipse says it caught an exception while trying to refactor, that the file doesn't exist, and lets me either undo, or abort. I suspect it has something to do with mercurial because it's happened before, but besides that, I have no idea what is wrong. Anyone know how to fix this? I've already tried refreshing the entire project, cleaning the project, and closing and reopening the project, but I still can't even move a source file from one project to another.

***UPDATE:***
I've resorted to using the command prompt to manually move and rename my files. It wasn't that hard, but Eclipse is still not doing what it's supposed to do. I want to know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possibly related to this:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339866

I found updating both eclipse and hg fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project and click refresh.  This is usually due to files being out of sync with the file system.

Comment: You can try deleting the project ( make sure the box marked delete from filesystem is unchecked) then "Import existing projects" back into the workspace.  That works sometimes.  I'll ponder on it some more and get back to you tmw :)